# Font Awesome Icon inline with headline and text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a nice layout for product descriptions using font awesome icons, headline and paragraph text with HTML & CSS .

This will be used in WooCommerce single product pages, so I'm trying to avoid inline styling so that I can put the HTML code in the WordPress wysiwyg editor and CSS in the stylesheet.

I've created a visual example of the layout I'm trying to create, but I'm not sure what is practice to achieve it.

[image]

Below is the code so far, could anybody please help to stack the display so that icon, headline, text appear together like image but on top of each other inside of flexed / side to side

[Code Pen Link](https://codepen.io/Rosko34/pen/bGrvqzP)

[image]

HTML

```
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="propertydescription_wrapper">
  
<div class="icon">
<i class="fas fa-search-location fa-3x"></i>
</div>
<div class="text">
<h3>Headline</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut.
<p/>
</div>
  
<div class="icon">
<i class="fas fa-search-location fa-3x"></i>
</div>
<div class="text">
<h3>Headline</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut.
<p/>
</div>
  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.propertydescription_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.propertydescription_wrapper * {
 margin: 0px;
}

.propertydescription_wrapper .icon {
  color: #A7784A
}

.propertydescription_wrapper .text {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;

}

.propertydescription_wrapper .text h3 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-border" style=""></i>
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <h3>Headline</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut.
      <p/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wicked!! Thank you.

Comment: How do I stack the layout so that each seciton (icon, headline, text) still display on top of each other like the image in original post? Thanks -> https://codepen.io/Rosko34/pen/bGrvqzP